# Restricting floating point values in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, integer

I am using sqlite3 and I came across a strange issue.
For example, I  have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE demo (effort integer);


insert into demo values (10.5);  - works fine
insert into demo values (10.5);  - works fine
insert into demo values (10.5555);  - works fine
```

I have two concerns:

1.Why is it allowing float values when I have declared the datatype to be integer not real ? 
2.Is there any way, that I can restrict it upto 2 decimal places?

Is there any workaround so that I can restrict only integer values(strictly no floating values).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite [uses dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

To enforce the column type, add a constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE demo(
  effort INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(typeof(effort) = 'integer')
)
```